# Access SQL Query Top 1 of Group

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to write a query that selects the Top record in each Group of Data.

eg Below

| Division | Team | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Liverpool | 90 |
| 1 | Manchester | 88 |
| 2 | Leeds | 94 |
| 2 | Arsenal | 77 |
| 3 | Bolton | 66 |
| 3 | Spurs | 72 |
| 3 | Derby | 33 |

I want my query to return the team with highest number of points in each division:

| Division | Team | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Liverpool | 90 |
| 2 | Leeds | 94 |
| 3 | Spurs | 72 |

I thought this should be easy.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You can use rank() over parition by division and order by rank if available ?  Else you need to use group by to find the top point by division and self join with the table to get the team name. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what Self Join means. Could You write the SQL query for me? It cant be more than a couple of lines

Answer (score 2):

In MS Access, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.points = (select max(t2.points)
                  from t t2
                  where t2.division = t.division
                 );
```

If there are ties, then this returns all matching teams.  If you want only one team even when there are ties:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.team = (select t2.team
                from t t2
                where t2.division = t.division
                order by t2.points desc, t2.team
               );
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon that's perfect. I can just about get my head around that!

Comment: Then please mark the answer as accepted. Tick the answer.